# Export equivalent in windows for using Tensorflow object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been trying to install Tensorflow Object Detection API, and I've encountered the following error:

```
import error :no module named ' nets ' and the solution is by setting the python path like this :export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

But what is the equivalent of this in Windows?

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
set PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`../tensorflow/model`:`../tensorflow/models/slim`
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nets'`.
In **Windows**, go to `models-master\models-master\research\slim` *directory* and run the following command in CMD:

```
python setup.py install
```