# How to resolve Import Error for 'Deeplab' -- Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pythonpath, deeplab

I'm following Beeren Sahu's guide for using DeepLab in Tensorflow: https://beerensahu.wordpress.com/2018/04/17/guide-for-using-deeplab-in-tensorflow/

I'm trying to use DeepLab model for semantic segmentation in TensorFlow. I've downloaded the DeepLab code here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models

After running:

```
hpcsub -cmd python3.4 model_test.py
```

I'm get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_test.py", line 20, in <module>
    from deeplab import common
ImportError: No module named 'deeplab'
```

Basically complaining about line 20 in model_test.py:

```
from deeplab import common
```

I understand that it's a 'deeplab' dependency error, however I do not know how to resolve it. As Sahu's tutorial recommended, I added both of the below libraries:

```
# From tensorflow/models/research/ 
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/deeplab
```

And with these two export commands, I still get the same result.

I've found others with a similar issue on Github, but they have yet to find a solution: 
1--  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5214
2--  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4364

***If you don't have a solution, but can recommend helpful tutorials on using Google's open sourced DeepLab-v3 for semantic image segmentation please share!!***

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but try this

```
set PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`../tensorflow/model`:`../tensorflow/models/slim`
```

i found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091402/6355940)

Answer (score 0):

What is the path of your current working directory?

You need to run export command and the script from tensorflow/model/research directory.

```
$ cd /path/to/tensorflow
$ cd models/research
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/deeplab
$ python deeplab/model_test.py
```

The output of this script would be like this.

```
.....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 19.040s

OK
```